# what is wrong with below c++ code?

Tags: c++

I came across a question while reading c++ primer and I am wondering what is wrong with the code below

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Nodefault
{
        int a;
public:
        Nodefault(int j):a(j){};
};

class c
{
        int a ;
public:
        c(int b ):a(b){};
        c(){};
        Nodefault n(5) ;
};

int main()
{
        c obj;

        return 0;
}
```

Why I am unable to create an object of class c here with Nodefault
 class as its member ?

Below is the Error from the compiler :

> error: expected identifier before numeric constant wrong2.cpp:18:14:
>   error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant

Comment: I bet the compiler tells you. If you are having trouble understanding the compiler error message, please show us the message and ask about it.

Comment: Don't mark everything as quotes.

Comment: Why did you post tons of pointless noise? Who needs iostreams, namespace std and return 0? None of those add any value to the question.

Comment: `Nodefault n(5) ;` is not a valid member declaration.

Comment: Ok guys the question may not be of any value to you.But I have just started to learn c++ ,so just thought of asking it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You defined n in the wrong place.

In fact, you also need to construct `n` in the default constructor of `c`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Nodefault
{
    int a;
public:
    Nodefault(int j):a(j){};
};

class c
{
    int a ;
public:
    c(int b ) : a(b), n(5) {};
    c() : n(5) {};
    Nodefault n;
};

int main()
{
    c obj;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C++11 or later, you could change the declaration to `Nodefault n{5};` or `Nodefault n=5;`, instead of adding to the constructor's initialiser list.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the default constructor of `class C`, compiler has no way to initialize your `Nodefault` object, as there's no default constructor available for that class.

assuming by

```
Nodefault n(5) ;
```

you mean

```
Nodefault n ;
```

Answer (score 0):

For C++03 the syntax is:

```
class c
{
    int a;
public:
    c(int b): a(b), n(5) {}
    c(): n(5) {}
    Nodefault n;
};
```